# Create automatically temperature or isotherms map with PostGIS?

Tags: postgis, geoserver

Is there any possibility to create automatically temperature or isotherms map through a points table stored in PostGIS? 
I need to serve this map on a web (Geoserver). The information is updated each hour and I need to have the map updated as well.

Comment: I'm asking if there is any way to create this map through postgis points table. I've created this map manually with qgis and later I have published it in Geoserver. I wonder if there is  any way to do it automatically.

Comment: I'm asking if you tried anything in PostGIS and Geoserver so far. Do you care weather the result is a temp raster or isotherms vector?

Comment: Sorry I haven't tried anything. I don't care the result format, I only want to have the result map updated on the web

Answer (score 1):

For that kind of task you can use the [rendering transformations](http://suite.opengeo.org/docs/latest/cartography/rt/index.html) of geoserver.They allow set a SLD style that uses some predefined WPS process to style your layers.

Boundless has an example that fits pretty well in your case, it shows how to chain a Barnes Surface process with a Contour process to [generate a contour map of estimated average temperatures](http://boundlessgeo.com/2013/01/chaining-rendering-transformations-in-geoserver/).